# error for routing in [GET] "/articles/new"'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I'm going through "Getting Started with Rails" and I'm stuck on Chapter 5.1. I tried:

```
rails g controller articles
```

I tried to open the `articles/new`, I get this error message below:

```
No route matches [GET] "/articles/new"
Rails.root: C:/Sites/blog
```

Then I run `rake routes` and my command prompts:

```
You don't have any routes defined!  Please add some routes in config/routes.rb'
```

Here is my `routes.rb`:

```
  Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `resources :articles` to `routes.rb`:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
  resources :articles
end
```

You can learn more about routing in the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.  That was actually mentioned  in the tutorial, but it wasn't super explicit.  I.E 'type this line into your routes.rb file'